# Google Search syntax to specify a language?

Tags: google-search

I can read a lot of languages and am charged with doing research about software in various countries. My Google interface is in English but I often have to search pages in a particular language, and 5 minutes later in another language.

Using the [Advanced Search](https://encrypted.google.com/advanced_search) page is very inconvenient because I always launch searches directly from the URL bar. Is there a way to specify the desired results language in the search syntax?

Note: The `hl` parameter is not a valid answer, it just changes the user interface's language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `lr` parameter format — `&lr=lang_short_language_code`.

English — en: `&lr=lang_en`

Ukrainian — uk: `&lr=lang_uk`

All language codes can be found in the source on advanced settings page.